# Creating .exe file of python project with selenium, requests_html and kivy

Tags: python, selenium, kivy, exe, python-requests-html

I have a project done in python that uses kivy for creating the GUI, and selenium and requests_html to do the methods. I have to create a .exe file of the project, but so far nothing worked.
I have tried to create the .exe with pyinstaller and cx_freeze, but both showed an error; i know that some people do have had a pretty bad time while creating a .exe file of a project using requests_html and selenium, but i know it is possible. The python project contains both the webdriver and its respective web version (to make sure it will work), but it does not contain the Chromium requests_html uses to work. I do not know what to do or use; have tried 2 times to create the .exe and in the first time requests_html returned an error (pyinstaller), and the second one kivy returned an error (cx_freeze).
Can you help me solve the problem? I really have no clue at all of what to do

Comment: Maybe you can show the error? Try `pyinstall --onefile`

Comment: Using pyinstaller --onefile main.py at the directory of the project, the exe file that should be in dist was not created, and in powershell the followind error appeared: error:(110, 'EndUpdateResourceW, 'The sistem could not open the specified file')

Comment: Then you probably have some incompatible paths in your project. try to run pyinstaller from the same path you're launching the file from.

Comment: I executed the pyinstaller directly from the directory where the main.py file is located (it is in the form DIRECTORY --> main.py, edge_webdriver, edge, __pycache__ (automatically created by vscode), and the Database directory where is __init__.py).